# Notepad++ Regex to Insert Line between certain lines

Tags: regex, string, notepad++

I was trying this in Notepad++, but I'm not entirely sure if it's possible there.  I have an iCal file where I need to insert some missing "Organizer" fields.  For example, I need

```
DTSTAMP:20140821T160519Z
UID:ExampleUID1
```

to be this

```
DTSTAMP:20140821T160519Z
ORGANIZER;CN=Test:mailto:me@example.com
UID:ExampleUID1
```

The organizer is there in some cases, and is **not** a static value.  How can I do this while keeping the DTSTAMP string intact?  Finding DTSTAMP:[A-Za-z0-9_]*$\r\nUID: finds the entries, but I can't find out what to replace with. Using

```
DTSTAMP:^([A-Za-z0-9_])*$\r\nORGANIZER;CN=Test:mailto:me@example.com\r\nUID:
```

or any variation thereof injects the actual regex text (^[A-Za-z0-9_]*$.) into the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this pattern:

```
^(DTSTAMP:.+)$
```

With this replacement string:

```
\1\r\nORGANIZER;CN=Test:mailto:me@example.com
```

You have to check the *Regular expression* mode (obviously), and uncheck the *. matches newline* option.

For some additional security, you also cound use this pattern:

```
^(DTSTAMP:.+)$(?!\r\nORGANIZER)
```

This won't insert an `ORGANIZER` field if one already exists just below the `DTSTAMP` field.

Also, if your iCal file is in UNIX newline format, replace every `\r\n` with `\n`.

Comment: The organizer is there in some cases, and is not guaranteed to be static...should have maybe mentioned that (have added).  This is perfect, though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
(DTSTAMP.*)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/cP4wO7/1)**

Check the substitution section:

[image]